# update row value based on if else condition

Tags: php, mysql, sql, if-statement

In php Page once we click on "**Submit**" button , in database we are saving order id, its working fine....

[image]

**Requirement** :

If payment is "Cash on delivery" , than i want to save order id in **"awb_type : COD"** row.... otherwise in **"awb_type : PPD"** row....

[image]

here is full code , track.php : https://pastebin.com/zLjpee7A ,  call.php : https://pastebin.com/4LkcxTYE

But orders are updating twice in table - one row in PPD & one in COD

[image]

Please let me know if you need more information....

**Update 2 :**

Now i tried below code, but whatever is payment_type , its **saving only in awb_type column : PPD rows**....

```
$sqlc = "select * from ecomexpress_awb WHERE status='unused' AND awb_type='COD' limit 1"; 
$resultc = $db_handle->runSelectQuery($sqlc); 

$sqld = "select * from ecomexpress_awb WHERE status='unused' AND awb_type='PPD' limit 1"; 
$resultd = $db_handle->runSelectQuery($sqld);

$payment_type='';
$sqlg="SELECT * FROM do_order where payment_type='".$payment_type."'";
$resultg = $db_handle->runSelectQuery($sqlg);

if($payment_type=="Cash on delivery")
{
$awb = $resultc[0]['awb']; 
$sqle = "update ecomexpress_awb set orderid = '".$order_id."',status='used' WHERE awb ='".$awb."' limit 1"; 
$resulte = $db_handle->runSelectQuery($sqle);
}
else
{
$awba = $resultd[0]['awb'];
$sqlf = "update ecomexpress_awb set orderid = '".$order_id."',status='used' WHERE awb ='".$awba."' limit 1";    
$resultf = $db_handle->runSelectQuery($sqlf);
}
```

Comment: if you want to stop it updating twice then the UPDATE statment would also have to be within your if/else block. Right now you seem to only have the select statements within that.

Comment: BTW if you have multiple users on your system simultaneously then this system of picking the next unused slot is going to result in contention - i.e. people selecting and/or updating the same rows as each other. e.g. user1 runs select, slot 23 was available, but user2 also runs and gets slot 23 as available, then user1 runs update, and then user2 runs update (and thus overwrites user1's data). It would be better to just create the AWB records at the time you need them, surely, instead of creating them ahead or time. That or you have to find a way to lock the rows.

Comment: *I tried if else condition* ... where is this if/else block? Also, what is the logic to decide PPD and COD. Your posted update query does not have an `awb_type` condition (but select queries do).

Comment: @ADyson i am using condition that if `status='unused'` , than only rows are going to update, so if user1 runs update , `slot 23 will become status='used'` , so when user2 also runs update , it will not update again right ? because already `slot 23 will become status='used'` , will it work ?

Comment: Yes but it will overwrite the order number with user2's order number, and user1's order number will be lost

Comment: @ADyson Thanks for reply , but once user1 update, already status will change to `used`..... still how user2 can update the same row ?

Comment: A better solution to this would be some sort of message queue containing the pre-issed AWB numbers, and then your code would simply pick the next item off the top of the queue. The queue system would ensure that each separate request is given a new number. And only then would you write the row into the database. A SQL table is the wrong tool for storing and allowing the consumption a list of pre-assigned numbers. Use the right tool for the job.

Comment: @ADyson can you suggest me what tool will help me in this case? is there any php code that will help me ?

Comment: @vickeycolors it will still overwrite because the value of the awb ID that user2 is using is the same as the value that user1 is using. So they both target the same row. This is because user2 requested the latest awb ID at the same moment that user1 did, before user1 had chance to run the update. A webserver can execute multiple requests in parallel.

Comment: You could use some queuing software like MSMQ or rabbitmq or something cloud based. There are literally dozens of implementations, if you search. A message queue system can have lots of uses, so you should choose something to suit you in future as well.

Comment: @ADyson okay, until we implement those tools, we will make sure it should be used by only one user.....

Comment: In the meantime, if you don't have time for that now then you'll have to put a lock on the SQL table instead. Open the lock before you select the AWB ID and close it after you run the update. It's a quick fix but will slow your application down if it has multiple users, because each must wait for the lock to be released by another user before it can do anything to the table. If you have more than a handful of simultaneous users it will get slow

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184171/discussion-between-vickey-colors-and-adyson).

Comment: @ADyson Thanks for helping me on holiday..... i appreciate your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before I did't binded the payment_type with order_id, below code worked for me :

```
if(isset($_POST['order_id']) && $_POST['order_id']!='')
{ 
$order_id = $_POST['order_id'];  
$payment_type=$_POST['payment_type'];

$sqlg="SELECT * FROM do_order where payment_type='".$payment_type."'";
$resultg = $db_handle->runSelectQuery($sqlg);

if($payment_type=="Cash on delivery")
{
  $sqlc = "select * from ecomexpress_awb WHERE status='unused' AND awb_type='COD' limit 1"; 
}
else
{
  $sqlc = "select * from ecomexpress_awb WHERE status='unused' AND awb_type='PPD' limit 1"; 
}

$resultc = $db_handle->runSelectQuery($sqlc);
```